# Cumulative distribution of Binomial Random variable

Tags: distributions, probability, binomial-distribution

How to prove this:

**Proposition.** If $F_n$ is the distribution function of a $\textrm{Bin}(n,p)$ random variable, then, for every real fixed $t$, the sequence $\{F_n(t)\}_{n=1}^\infty$ is nonincreasing.

P.S. There was some heavy editing here.

Comment: I don't follow your argument at all.  Isn't the question whether or not when n$_1$>n$_2$ P{X$_1$<=k)<P{X$_2$<=k} for each k<=n$_2$?  I don't even think this is true.  It could depend on p.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Suppose that you have a sequence
$$
  Y_1,Y_2,Y_3,\dots
$$
of independent and identically distributed random variables such that $Y_1\sim\textrm{Bernoulli}(p)$.

Define $F_n(t)=P\left\{\sum_{i=1}^n Y_i\leq t\right\}$, which is the distribution function of a $\textrm{Bin}(n,p)$ random variable.

If $\sum_{i=1}^n Y_i>t$, then $\sum_{i=1}^{n+1} Y_i>t$. Hence, we have the inclusion
$$
  \left\{\omega:\sum_{i=1}^n Y_i(\omega)>t\right\} \subset \left\{\omega:\sum_{i=1}^{n+1} Y_i(\omega)>t\right\} \, ,
$$
and it follows from the monotonicity of $P$ that
$$
  P\left\{\omega:\sum_{i=1}^n Y_i(\omega)>t\right\} \leq P\left\{\omega:\sum_{i=1}^{n+1} Y_i(\omega)>t\right\} \, ,
$$
which is equivalent to
$$
  1-F_n(t)\leq 1-F_{n+1}(t) \, ,
$$
and so
$$
  F_n(t)\geq F_{n+1}(t) \, ,
$$
yielding that, for each fixed $t$, the sequence of real numbers $\{a_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ defined by $a_n=F_n(t)$ is nonincreasing.

Comment: It this is what the OP intended, may I edit his question to reflect that? Sorry for the little JMRT here.

Comment: Thanks, Zen. This is what I was thinking. Please edit the questions as needed.

Comment: Is it "legal" for me to edit your question?

Comment: Either one of you can do it. But if you do it and there are not enough characters changed StackRxchange won't allow it.  But the Op is not restricted.

Comment: Just edited. Tks, Michael.

Comment: (+1) Hopefully the OP will notice that the binomial distribution enters in only in the most nominal way in the proof. Indeed, this is true for any family of distributions formed from sums of exchangeable nonnegative random variables.

Comment: (+1) Nice comment. Just nonnegative would do the job, right? I think that the underlying sequence doesn't need to be exchangeable.

Comment: Hi, Zen. The reason I included *exchangeable* was a conceptual one in that the notion of $F_n$ is a little more meaningfully defined. (The point being, no notion of sequence is really necessary. I *did* waffle considerably on whether to include this, though.) Otherwise, if your set of random variables is in a distinguished order (e.g., as a discrete-time stochastic process) and $F_n$ is the distribution of the sum of the first $n$ in the sequence, then, clearly, the result still holds as you've noted, with no restriction on the dependence between the variables. :-)

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, Cardinal. I see that is true. Thanks to all for making editing the problem and giving nice proof. Hannah

Comment: Yeah, cardinal, not even independence is needed. However, since "exchangeability" sounds like music to my Bayesian ears, I like the way you stated the result.

Comment: You are welcome, @user131154! If you like it, you may consider checking the answer as such.